# Livereload not working with Ionic serve command

Tags: ionic-framework

I run:

```
 ionic serve
 ✗ (node:7616) fs: re-evaluating native module sources is not supported. If you are using the graceful-fs module, please update it to a more recent version.
Running dev server: http://localhost:8100
Running live reload server: http://localhost:35729
Watching : [ 'www/**/*', '!www/lib/**/*' ]
Ionic server commands, enter:
  restart or r to restart the client app from the root
  goto or g and a url to have the app navigate to the given url
  consolelogs or c to enable/disable console log output
  serverlogs or s to enable/disable server log output
  quit or q to shutdown the server and exit
```

My chrome starts with livereload activated
[image]

My source code contains

```
<script>//<![CDATA[
document.write('<script src="//' + (location.hostname || 'localhost') + ':35729/livereload.js?snipver=1"><\/script>')
//]]></script>
```

IOnic detects changes on file:

```
ionic $ JS changed:   C:\Users\Proxymis\Desktop\ionic\Monuma\www\js\controllers.js
JS changed:   C:\Users\Proxymis\Desktop\ionic\Monuma\www\js\controllers.js
```

When I open the local host on port 35729 I got

```
{"tinylr":"Welcome","version":"0.0.5"}
```

**But when I modify my page, my page NEVER reloads !**